# I have a CSV generated from CICFLOWMETER and I'm unable generate a correlation matrix It either generates a empty data frame

Tags: python, csv, correlation, valueerror, emptydatatext

This is the code I'm using and I have also tried converting my datatype of my columns which is object to float but I got this error

```
df = pd.read_csv('DDOSping.csv')
pearsoncorr = df.corr(method='pearson')
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> '172.27.224.251-172.27.224.250-56003-502-6'

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your CSV this string value exists '172.27.224.251-172.27.224.250-56003-502-6'. Do you know why it's there? What does it represent? It looks to me like it shouldn't be in the data you include in your correlation matrix calculation.

The `df.corr` method is trying to convert the string value to a float, but it's obviously not possible to do because it's a big complicated string with various characters, not a regular number.

You should clean your CSV of unnecessary data (or make a copy and clean that so you don't lose anything important). Remove anything, like metadata, that isn't the exact data that `df.corr` needs, including the string in the error message.

If it's just a few values you need to clean then just open in excel or a text editor to do the cleaning. If it's a lot and all the irrelevant data to be removed is in specific rows and/or columns, you could just remove them from your DataFrame before calling 'df.corr' instead of cleaning the file itself.

Comment: Hey its network data like IP addresses and Flow IDs all data is of similar sort. They are 84 features I need to find relation in them , via any method. If you could suggest any method?